# Img location/src replacement with a php or javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, image

Hi all
I have a question as i just seen a script which could possibly help but am limited in my understanding of javascript or even php.

the pieces of coded i just seen:

```
$(function() {
    $("img")
        .hover(function() { 
            var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "over.gif";
            $(this).attr("src", src);
        })
});

$('img.swap').hover(function () {
    this.src = '/images/signup_big_hover.png';
}, function () {
    this.src = '/images/signup_big.png';
});
```

basically I have a very large site and have images all over the place in various folders, now I want to move them all into one folder in root, without having to change the 300+ pages....
Is it possible to change the image path from what is stated in the src to an alternative with such a script? Would appreciated any help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could manipulate the src of each img elements in your page with jQuery. However:

a/ The function that you show is applied to the images on mouse over, that;'s not what you want.

b/ I'd recommend to do that with a search and replace on all your site's pages or DB entries instead of doing it with JavaScript dynamically. I think the use of a PHP variable to set your image path is the best and most flexible solution.

Comment: Naba thanks for the fast reply, the script above is just something i seen here and thought that it could possibly be changed to suite my needs.

Comment: You're right, that's the idea if you wanted to do it through JS. Using the the first function, just replace hover() by each(), and execute a function which will replace the src by a new one.

Comment: sorry return I did try to use dreamweaver to replace all img src to the new location but then found that it also changed alot of other content and would of taken even longer to replace or resolve. I guess even using php to define a path would involve changing all src tags in the pages. When i tried a php solution by defining I also ended up with more issues as soon as i increase the depth in folder structure, as i am using a single header for all pages, unless you know of way to automaticly increase the folder depth path with php which would be a great solution. Thanks

Comment: I suck at regular expression so I won't be of any help for the replacing function ;)

Comment: i did mention my scripting was limited, as in creating a new function to replace is out my scope at the moment, maybe in a few weeks of further studying lol

Comment: I suck at regular expressions... except with Dreamweaver! (but I'm generally ashame to say it here) What are the actual and new path?

Comment: actual is img/ in side of each folder, the new path would be up to 4 folders down so ../../../img , ../../img , ../img and img depending on the depth of the page/folder, I did try to add this to my first php attempt and failed like i never failed before lol

Comment: So that means you have to do it for each folder's level

Comment: Ideally you should replace all the occurences of img/ by a PHP var, and have this PHP var defined differently depending on the folder level you're at. Another possibility, but I'm not sure it works on Windows (if you care), is to put all your images in that new folder and to replace your img/ folders by symlinks

Comment: exactly what I tried the first time, before using dw to change or anything else, maybe I try that again if i cant find something easier than having to change each link which is exactly what i am trying to avoid. even thou this solution makes more sence even in the long run. thanks very much for ur input been a great help already

Comment: Ok. That's definitely the long term solution. One last thing, if ever you struggle with Dreamweaver, here's a regexp for img tag: <img([^>]*) src="([^"]+)"([^>]*)>

Comment: erm thanks but hate to ask what does it do in dw? of course i understand its a typical tag but everything within brackets other than the + and * makes no sense to my current understanding :)

Comment: Open one of your files with images in DW, Open Search & Replace checking "Use regular expressions". Put that in your search field: <img([^>]*) src="img/([^"]+)"([^>]*)> than this in your replace: <img$1 src="my_new_path/$2"$3> You should understand ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this with Dreamweaver using the integrated search & replace feature.

The feature gives you the option of searching through directories and modifying files based off of the parameters supplied.

Ex.

Search For: "images/lol.jpg"

Replace With: "new/lol.jpg"

If you do not have Dreamweaver, I recommend getting it because it's a great tool to have. :)

Comment: yeh I tried that one, thought it would be the easiest solution untill it changed alot more than i wanted and ended being double the work, hence the search for an alternative solution, thanks

Comment: of course wanting to avoid the update of every single image src, there are over 10k of them lol

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use something like this:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/SfJP9/1/

Is this what you were going for?

Like this you can get the `src` of the image

http://www.jsfiddle.net/UMQ5W/2/

Comment: any idea if it works with only a path, so if I would do the following: $('img').replaceWith('<img src="http://www.sandia.gov/media/images/jpg/">'); as in each page i have about 20-100 images, changing the dir in one go would be a god send

Comment: @Jamie that I think has to be done with a regex, give me a sec. Maybe http://api.jquery.com/prepend/ could be used too.

Comment: @Jamie could you please give me an "actual" example of how the links look now and how it should look, exactly.

Comment: i just tried the example, and it didnt work. the links are as basic as it gets: <img src="img/world.jpg" height="32" width="32" /> the img folder is currently located in the same folder as each page, with 20 folders depth of a maximum of 4 folders, all images are to be moved to the root folder so in the example here would be as such: <img src="../../img/world.jpg" height="32" width="32" /> or of course defining the entire path which i havent done in any src so far, so all have the same path as img/

Comment: @Jamie So, so every image will change from ../../ from 4 to 20 ../../img/world.jpg to img/world.jpg is that what you are saying?

Comment: the oposite, from img/ to ../../ and so on.

Comment: @Jamie that is a little more complex. So you said everything will be in the root, would you agree (to know we are speaking of the same thing here): if we counted the directories back to root and put one "../" for each and the /img/filename.jpg and did this programmatically it would solve the problem?

Comment: Trufa thanks for so far :) yes i think we are now on the same level, how ever replacing all with a ../ is what i was trying to avoid of course would mean to change all src tags and placing a a script to change the src would of saved me days of work lol but yes it is a solution one im trying to avoid

Comment: @Jamie could you please go to the chat  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/523/img-location-src-replacement-with-a-php-or-javascript so we could discuss it further, I think it will simplify things.

Comment: sorry been trying to get in the room for a while now and its just not loading the chat, maybe due to the connection here in the office. will keep trying thou :)

Comment: @Jamie no problem! maybe later you'll have a better connection! If you login let me know (you can send me a @Trufa message and I'll get notified)

Comment: @Trufa thanks again, not had any lucks keeps getting stuck on wait a few seconds. I have gone ahead and started changing for variables everywhere I am still however interested in an alt solution, may need for the future, plus am trying to learn as much as possible on the scripting side of things. Am just about to go home, will try form there, hopefully will be better.

Comment: @Jamie no hurries, make me a comment when you are home and we'll try to set it up!

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say but I guess the long dreaded way is the only solution, replacing each and every src tag to the new location.
Thanks all for the help and ideas been great and have actually learnt something which makes this an ever better experience. Thanks very much!
So my solution as much as I wanted to avoid it even thou it is in my best interest for now and future will be to replace all with variables and simply create a location file directing all src attribs to a single folder, going to be allot of work i didn't want.......
Maybe next time I think of the structure before going ahead and blasting out 300 pages with notepad lol

**Thanks again**